# jQuery UI Datepicker: restricting to fortnight

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I've done some searching and can't really seem to find a specific example of what I'm looking for (JS isn't my strong point). If there is another answer already provided, I apologise and would be eternally grateful for the link.

I'm currently building a pay calculator in PHP, with the datepicker on my front page to ensure consistency. We get paid fortnightly, and I want to make only those fortnightly dates available for selection. I've disabled all days bar Saturdays, but it allows all Saturdays. I figure there is probably a for loop or something I can use to count every second Saturday from a specified date to ensure the correct dates are shown, but as I said above, I'm not familiar with JS. (I would like to count from a specified date so it auto-updates and I don't have to hardcode the fortnight dates.)

My code was as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    beforeShowDay: nonWorkingDates,
});
function nonWorkingDates(date){
    var day = date.getDay(), Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, Wednesday = 3, Thursday = 4, Friday = 5, Saturday = 6;
    var closedDays = [[Sunday], [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday],];
    for (var i = 0; i < closedDays.length; i++) {
    if (day == closedDays[i][0]) {
        return [false];
    }
    }
    return [true];
}
});
```

But thanks to Badri, I've slimmed it down to:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    beforeShowDay: nonWorkingDates
});
function nonWorkingDates(date){
    if (date.getDay() != 6) {
        return [false, '', 'selected'];
    }
    return [true, ''];
}
});
```

As a related matter (which I'm happy to make a separate question if required), can I make datepicker show just those dates that you can select from? Or is there an alternative to datepicker that someone can suggest to achieve this?

Cheers

Comment: Can't you use the `maxDate` option for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this faq that shows how to allow users to select only specific days in a week:
http://jqfaq.com/how-to-restrict-date-selection-to-specifc-week-days-in-the-dropdown/

To allow every other saturdays from today only, your code would look slightly different like this:

```
function beforeShowDayHandler(date) {
    var today = new Date();
    if (date < today || date.getDay() != 6) {
        return [false, '', 'selected'];
    } else {
        var day = today.getDay();
        var comingSat = new Date();
        comingSat.setDate(comingSat.getDate() + 6 - day);
        var diffDays = dateDiffInDays(comingSat, date);
        var noOfWeeksAway = diffDays / 7;

        if ((noOfWeeksAway % 2 == false)) return [false, '', 'selected'];
    }
    return [true, ''];

}
```

Full functional fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/badri_cr/VNNYP/

Comment: I've changed my code to make it more readable based on this, so thank you!

I would like to enable the 2nd Saturday from a specified date, i.e. an earlier fortnight ending date, so the options available are restricted to fortnight ending.

Comment: Ok, so, you want to allow the 2nd, 3rd and every Sat in future from the specified date or you want to allow 2nd, 4th, 6th and so on from the specified date?

Comment: 2nd, 4th, 6th, etc.

For example, our next fortnight end date is 28/June/2014, so I would want this Sat (21/June/2014) and the 5th/July/2014 blocked out, but the 12/July/2014 available. So essentially set the start date as 28/June/2014, then +14 for the next available date. I apologise if this isn't any clearer.

Comment: Ok, I just changed the sample code above and also provided a link to the full fiddle. Please confirm and mark as answer.

Comment: I adjusted the function code with what you have posted, however it no longer brings up the calendar when I click on the button. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you refer the fiddle that has the full JS you need. The code above doesn't include the dateDiffInDays function code. In any case, if you get an error, check the browser's console (F12) that should give an idea on where the issue is.

Comment: Brilliant! I did copy the code, however I screwed up some other options I required. It's now working as planned, though one last question: where do I specify the start date for the fortnight count, i.e. 25 Oct 2013

Comment: Oh, if you want Oct 25, 2013 as the seed, replace this line: "var today = new Date();" in the beginning with that date. Please mark as Answered.

Answer (score 0):

use the options:

```
minDate: 0,
maxDate: '+14'
```

to limit the datepicker to the next fortnight.